# Hilos para mostrar contador JAVA SWING

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo la siguiente clase de Hilo

```
public class Hilo  extends Thread{

        public Hilo(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            int cantMaxima = Sistema.TIEMPO;
            int iterador = 0 ; 
            while(iterador<cantMaxima){

            Sistema.setContador(Sistema.getContador()-1);
            iterador++;
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Hilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }


    }
```

En mi Clase ControladorDeUnaVistaX hago lo siguiente

```
Hilo h1 = new Hilo("Contador");
        h1.start();
```

ahora en mi vista tengo lo siguiente

```
int cant = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog("El tiempo restante es "+Sistema.getContador());
```

el problema que me encuentro ahora es que no se como hacer para que se actualice el numero en el JPanel ,se queda estatico en el 0

Intente hacer refresh();
y revalidete():

La verdad nose si lo tengo mal encarado o asi se puede resolver el como mostrar un contador en un JPanel con un hilo haciendo el conteo regresivo

Comment: Por jpanel te refieres a tuJOptionPane? sino pon el código de tu JPanel

Comment: Perdon , si me refiero al JOptionsPane , O de ultima en Jpanel que me imagino que pasara lo mismo , ?

Comment: Se necesita un [mcve] para poder entender el problema.

Comment: Umm, yo no usaría `JOptionPane` para ese propósito, ademas entre otras cosas, se 'bloquearía' el flujo de la actualización que necesitas hasta dar clic en 'Ok' una y otra vez. Demasiado engorroso. ¿Porque no optas por un `JDialog`/`JFrame` comunes con el `JLabel` para mostrar el progreso?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿No sería mejor implementarlo con un timer?

Te ilustro un ejemplo:

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Eduardo Isaac Ballesteros
 */
public class TimerEjemplo2 {

    Timer timer;
    int contador = 0;
    int valorMaximo = 100;
    int valorInicial = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerEjemplo2 timerEjemplo2 = new TimerEjemplo2();
    }

    public TimerEjemplo2() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JLabel label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
                Hilo hilo = new Hilo("test");
                hilo.start();

                timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        label.setText(String.valueOf(valorInicial));
                        valorInicial++;
                        if (valorInicial == valorMaximo) {
                            timer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, label, "Ejemplo", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Una solución sucia con Thread sería así:

```
public class Sistema {
    private static int contador = 100;

    /**
     * @return the contador
     */
    public static int getContador() {
        return contador;
    }

    /**
     * @param aContador the contador to set
     */
    public static void setContador(int aContador) {
        contador = aContador;
    }
}


import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author Eduardo Isaac Ballesteros
 */
public class Hilo extends Thread {

    JLabel label;

    public Hilo(JLabel pLabel) {
        this.label = pLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int cantMaxima = 100;
        int iterador = 0;
        while (iterador < cantMaxima) {
            Sistema.setContador(Sistema.getContador() - 1);
            label.setText("Desde hilo: " + String.valueOf(Sistema.getContador()));
            iterador++;
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Hilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}


import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Eduardo Isaac Ballesteros
 */
public class TimerEjemplo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerEjemplo3 timerEjemplo3 = new TimerEjemplo3();
    }

    public TimerEjemplo3() {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        Hilo hilo = new Hilo(label);
        hilo.start();
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, label, "Ejemplo", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Se congela la pantalla porque el hilo no se esta ejecutando de forma independiente por lo que para que la pantalla se refresque te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           //Colocar todos los algoritmos aca
       }
   }).start();
```